# Graph API: All Mutual Friends Returning Empty List

Tags: facebook-graph-api

All mutual friends request made from my app server (node) (also tried the Facebook API explorer) suddenly started returning an empty array for the data field. I confirmed and validated my access token and appsecret_proof on the API explorer.  Do you know what has changed or what the request below is missing?

Note: both users use the app and have granted user_friends permission.

I am using v2.12

request
{
                url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/{user-facebookid}?fields=context.fields(all_mutual_friends.limit(5000))',
                qs: {access_token: 'XXXXX'
                ,
                appsecret_proof: crypto.createHmac('sha256', clientSecret).update(accessToken).digest('hex')

```
        }
```

Comment: did all the mutual friends you would like to see authorize your app too? i assume that´s why.

Comment: Yes. I verified the authorization (of the access tokens of both accounts) using the API explorer

Comment: This is live code, it was all working until two days ago.

Comment: both accounts...but what about the accounts of the mutual friends? did you miss the recent data scandal and the breaking changes?

Comment: so i have to ask again: did the MUTUAL friends authorize your app? are you really shure about that?

Comment: Oh, I see your point, at least one of the mutual friends also authorized the app. So in this specific scenario, I expect one mutual friend at least. Are you saying all mutual friends have to authorize the app? I thought the update just restricted the data you could get on the friends that have not authorized your app, i.e. you can only get the name if the friend has not authorized the app.

Comment: of course. people don´t show up anymore if they did not authorize your app too. you cannot even get the name of those people anymore, to protect their data.

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Facebook has taken down the Graph API for page access tokens. The only way to retrieve data (or was a week or so ago), was a temporary user token that lasts about 2 hours. It's totally broken my band's schedule page. I've been through every avenue and even spoke with a facebook ad team employee on the phone that was aware of it. She seemed to empathize but had no solution for me. I would count on it being down for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out a work around for this. On your fb application, you have to disable the secret key requirement. This can be found under the advance settings of your fb application console. It's called "
Require App Secret".

Once you generate a fb PAGE access token, you get a fb page token, and then extend it.
here is the token debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

You can extend the access token programmatically as explained here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

AND

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens

There is also an extend tool in the access token debugger.